# Apply Sorting in ListView Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a ListView, In which i want to enable the Sorting and Paging.

I have created my list view control as the following code:

```
  <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="CollegeDetailsView" 
        DataKeyNames="CollegeID" ItemType="CollegeDataLibrary.CollegeDetail"
        AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true"
        SelectMethod="GetData" OnItemDataBound="CollegeDetailsView_ItemDataBound">
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            There are no entries found for Colleges
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><asp:LinkButton ID="lbEmpID" CommandArgument="CollegeName" CommandName="Sort" Text="College Name" runat="server" /></th>
                        <th>Contact Person</th>
                        <th>Phone No</th>
                        <th>Email ID</th>
                        <th>FDP</th>
                        <th><asp:LinkButton ID="lbEmpName" CommandArgument="FirstVisitDate" CommandName="Sort" Text="First Visit" runat="server" /></th>
                        <th>Workshops</th>
                        <th>Created By</th>
                        <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
```

The GetData method is as follows:

```
public List<CollegeDataLibrary.CollegeDetail> GetData()
    {

        var context = DataOperations.GetCollegeDetails();
        return context.ToList();
    }
```

The GetDetails method:

```
public IEnumerable<CollegeDetail> GetCollegeDetails()
    {
        using (CollegeDataEntities context = new CollegeDataEntities())
        {
            return context.CollegeDetails.ToList();
        }            
    }
```

Now when i click on the CollegeName in the browser, it is showing the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return a IQueryable object

```
public IQueryable<CollegeDataLibrary.CollegeDetail> GetData()
{
    var context = DataOperations.GetCollegeDetails();
    return context.AsQueryable();
}
```

Don't forget to add a reference to System.Linq